# Google Navigation forgets/ignores "Access to my location" setting - Nexus 4

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, gps, google-maps-navigation

Every time I attempt to use Google Maps Navigation on my stock (rooted) Nexus 4, I get the `Searching for GPS` screen.  The phone never finds GPS though.

I've found that if I go to `Settings`>`Location Access` and switch`Access to my location` off and on again the Navigation app finds GPS instantly, every time.

Nevertheless, the next time I try to use navigation, I will have to do this again.

Has this been reported as a bug anywhere, or is there a fix?

I'm on Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the Yahoo Weather app worked for me.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2293566&page=2